# How to count the number of rows coming out of a too many relationships where there are two conditions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to count the number of rows coming out of a too many relationships where there are two conditions. The query is below:

```
$follow = count($profiles->follow->where('follow_id', $account)->where('user_id', $user));
```

I currently have entries in follow_id as 17 and in the user_id as 16.

A dump of `$account` and `$user` shows the data is correct.

The result is currently coming back as 0 where I am looking for it to be 1.

Thanks

Comment: Post the result of `dd($profiles->follow->where('follow_id', $account)->where('user_id', $user));`

Comment: `Collection {#209 ▼
  #items: []
}` It's empty

Comment: I guess you shoul use where('id', $account) if you choose from follow table.

Comment: @JamesParsons Adjust your query until the returned Collection is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$follow = $profiles->follow->where('follow_id', $account)->where('user_id', $user)->count();
```